# jaxws-maven-plugin: The class "org.mainco.orgws.OrganizationWebService" is not an endpoint implementation class

Tags: web-services, maven, jax-ws, webservice-client

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I want to generate local WSDL files using the jaxws-maven-plugin, but am confused about what value I need to put for the "<SEI>" tag.  My Maven plugin code is

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <wsdlUrls>
                                                            <wsdlUrl>${wsdl.url}</wsdlUrl>
                                                    </wsdlUrls>
                                                    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                                                    <packageName>org.mainco.orgws</packageName>
                                            </configuration>
                                    </execution>
                                    <execution>
                                            <!-- generate WSDL file from the compiled classes in tmp directory -->
                                            <id>generate wsdl file</id>
                                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>wsgen</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <sei>org.mainco.orgws.OrganizationWebService</sei>
                                                    <destDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</destDir>
                                                    <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                                                    <resourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</resourceDestDir>
                                                    <packageName>org.mainco.orgws</packageName>
                                            </configuration>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Upon running this ("mvn clean test") there's only one interfaces generated that is annotated with a "@WebService" annotation ...

```
./src/main/java/org/mainco/orgws/OrganizationWebService.java
```

but there is no class generated that implements this interace.  When I run my plugin, I get the error

```
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:1.10:wsgen (generate wsdl file) @ orgsclient ---
The class "org.mainco.orgws.OrganizationWebService" is not an endpoint implementation class.
```

What class do I need to look for to figure out how to populate the <sei> tag?

**Edit:** Per the comment, here's the code of that class.  It's absolutely massive, so I left out a couple of methods, but hopefully it helps explains things.

```
package org.mainco.myws;

import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.3-b02-
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "OrganizationWebService", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface OrganizationWebService {


    /**
     * 
     * @param referenceDomain
     * @param appId
     * @return
     *     returns org.mainco.myws.ReferenceDomainResponse
     * @throws BusinessServiceFaultException
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getReferenceDomain", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetReferenceDomain")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getReferenceDomainResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetReferenceDomainResponse")
    public ReferenceDomainResponse getReferenceDomain(
        @WebParam(name = "appId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer appId,
        @WebParam(name = "referenceDomain", targetNamespace = "")
        ReferenceDomain referenceDomain)
        throws BusinessServiceFaultException
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param orgDatasetList
     * @param orgId
     * @param aiDomain
     * @param appId
     * @return
     *     returns org.mainco.myws.OrgData
     * @throws BusinessServiceFaultException
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getOrgData", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetOrgData")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getOrgDataResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetOrgDataResponse")
    public OrgData getOrgData(
        @WebParam(name = "appId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer appId,
        @WebParam(name = "orgId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer orgId,
        @WebParam(name = "aiDomain", targetNamespace = "")
        AiDomain aiDomain,
        @WebParam(name = "orgDatasetList", targetNamespace = "")
        OrgDatasetList orgDatasetList)
        throws BusinessServiceFaultException
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param orgType
     * @param orgId
     * @param relationshipType
     * @param appId
     * @param educationPeriodCd
     * @param orgSubTypeCd
     * @return
     *     returns org.mainco.myws.ParentOrgData
     * @throws BusinessServiceFaultException
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getParentOrgData", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetParentOrgData")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getParentOrgDataResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetParentOrgDataResponse")
    public ParentOrgData getParentOrgData(
        @WebParam(name = "appId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer appId,
        @WebParam(name = "orgId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer orgId,
        @WebParam(name = "relationshipType", targetNamespace = "")
        OrgRelationshipType relationshipType,
        @WebParam(name = "educationPeriodCd", targetNamespace = "")
        String educationPeriodCd,
        @WebParam(name = "orgType", targetNamespace = "")
        OrgType orgType,
        @WebParam(name = "orgSubTypeCd", targetNamespace = "")
        String orgSubTypeCd)
        throws BusinessServiceFaultException
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param appId
     * @param suppressRequestorEmail
     * @param orgDataChange
     * @param requestInfo
     * @return
     *     returns java.lang.Integer
     * @throws BusinessServiceFaultException
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "requestOrgDataChange", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.RequestOrgDataChange")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "requestOrgDataChangeResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.RequestOrgDataChangeResponse")
    public Integer requestOrgDataChange(
        @WebParam(name = "appId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer appId,
        @WebParam(name = "requestInfo", targetNamespace = "")
        OrgDataChangeRequestInfo requestInfo,
        @WebParam(name = "orgDataChange", targetNamespace = "")
        OrgDataChangeInfo orgDataChange,
        @WebParam(name = "suppressRequestorEmail", targetNamespace = "")
        Boolean suppressRequestorEmail)
        throws BusinessServiceFaultException
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param orgId
     * @param testProgram
     * @param appId
     * @param educationPeriodCd
     * @return
     *     returns org.mainco.myws.OrgReportsAvailableResponse
     * @throws BusinessServiceFaultException
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getOrgReportsAvailable", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetOrgReportsAvailable")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getOrgReportsAvailableResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetOrgReportsAvailableResponse")
    public OrgReportsAvailableResponse getOrgReportsAvailable(
        @WebParam(name = "appId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer appId,
        @WebParam(name = "orgId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer orgId,
        @WebParam(name = "educationPeriodCd", targetNamespace = "")
            String educationPeriodCd,
        @WebParam(name = "testProgram", targetNamespace = "")
        TestProgramType testProgram)
        throws BusinessServiceFaultException
    ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param orgType
     * @param appId
     * @param educationPeriodCd
     * @param parentOrgId
     * @param orgSubTypeCd
     * @return
     *     returns java.util.List<org.mainco.myws.OrgChildrenList>
     * @throws BusinessServiceFaultException
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getCrossProgramChildren", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetCrossProgramChildren")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getCrossProgramChildrenResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/myws/", className = "org.mainco.myws.GetCrossProgramChildrenResponse")
    public List<OrgChildrenList> getCrossProgramChildren(
        @WebParam(name = "appId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer appId,
        @WebParam(name = "parentOrgId", targetNamespace = "")
        Integer parentOrgId,
        @WebParam(name = "educationPeriodCd", targetNamespace = "")
        String educationPeriodCd,
        @WebParam(name = "orgType", targetNamespace = "")
        OrgType orgType,
        @WebParam(name = "orgSubTypeCd", targetNamespace = "")
        String orgSubTypeCd)
        throws BusinessServiceFaultException
    ;

...
}
```

Comment: post the code of `org.mainco.orgws.OrganizationWebService` here

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo : you have declared  `<packageName>org.mainco.orgws</packageName>` in your `pom.xml` but `OrganizationWebService` package is `org.mainco.myws` ?